Market make when the orderbook has very few orders/volume in it? (price is stable at $10)
Imagine a stock that's very unpopular, to the point where there'll only be on average 4 units of the stock at any given moment in the orderbook.
This stock is also stable at a price of \$10 (meaning that the price may go up or down \$1, but it'll always bounce back relatively quickly to \$10)
All bids in the orderbook are a maximum of $8.
All asks in the orderbook are a minimum of $12
There's a very clear Market Making opportunity here, where I could take the best bid or best ask at any given moment. And just undercut it by \$1. I make money off of letting people buy/sell at a price closer to the mid-price. The profit I get being the size of the spread.
Is there a better strategy that could be done here though, depending on the volume available at each pricing point in the orderbook?
Also, would anyone happen to have any good resources for learning to market make & market take in a high-frequency scenario or Arbitrage Tading between markets? I understand distributions and statistical models pretty well, and can code, but I just don't understand the finance jargon or strategies very well.
I'm quite a beginner in this field at the moment. Especially in different unique scenarios, I feel like I need to read more on different cases, and some good strategies in scenarios like the one I've given in this question.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Probably helpful: Market making in thinly traded assets. You didn't mention trade intensity, which is important as you expect your orders to be hit by market orders to make the spread. If there are only a few trades every day then your strategy won't have enough turnover to make it worth your while. On the other hand, when the book is thin the price might change dramatically when a big market order arrives and imposes a much bigger inventory risk when you are adversely selected.
